# Hashset in vyper

Tags: vyper

Does vyper have an equivalent of a hashset? The documentation doesn't say anything about a hashset, but given the existence of a hashmap, I imagine a hashset would be simple to have.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to use a separate type. You can use a hashmap with bool as target type

```
exampleSet: HashMap[address, bool]
```

Then you can use

```
if exampleSet[msg.sender]:
    # Remove msg.sender
    exampleSet[msg.sender] = False
else:
    # Add msg.sender
    exampleSet[msg.sender] = True
```